# Align UIScrollView contents to center of screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a  `scrollview` with 3 labels. `leftSide` `50` pixels width, `center` `50` pixels width and `rightside` `50` pixels width. When `scrollview` moves right I want to move previous the label (i.e. left label) to center of the screen.

If scrollView move left i want to move next label (i.e right label) to centre of the screen.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What have u tried so far? It can be easily done by using page control.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this?that is why asked question..

Comment: Then it shows lack of research! you must brush up your basics then.

Comment: i am not expecting exact code. expecting suggestion from others..

Comment: http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html